# Tool to generate state transition diagram for acts_as_state_machine

Tags: ruby, data-visualization, fsm, aasm, acts-as-state-machine

The ruby gem `acts_as_state_machine` can be super helpful for modeling object lifecycles within a flexible finite state machine framework. But I often find myself wanting a visual representation of the state transitions.

Is there a tool to generate an FSM diagram (state diagram flowchart, state/event table, UML, etc.) from an existing ruby class that `acts_as_state_machine`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`state_machine` gem](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) (not to be confused with `acts_as_state_machine`) [has this functionality](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#generating-graphs).

For example, from the docs:

```
$ rake state_machine:draw FILE=vehicle.rb CLASS=Vehicle
```

---

`state_machine` is no longer maintained. Its fork [`state_machines`](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines) has extracted diagram functionality into a separate gem [state_machines-graphviz](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines-graphviz). Installing that gem, and then run the renamed rake task:

```
$ rake state_machines:draw FILE=vehicle.rb CLASS=Vehicle
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/padde/stateoscope gem works with the AASM gem (previously known as acts_as_state_machine)

Answer (score 1):

A very late response but I'm using AASM and I've got the same problem. Forget about the `state_machine` gem. It hasn't been updated for 4 years now and doesn't look like it ever will. The best option I've found for AASM, is to download `OpenOffice` and use the `OpenOffice Draw` tool to generate a flow diagram. `OpenOffice` is free and it's very easy to use.

Obviously it would be far better if this was supported internally by AASM. Unfortunately it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Check [aasm-diagram](https://github.com/Katee/aasm-diagram) gem, seems newer.